# .htaccess redirect all sub directories under sub directory

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all sub directories under sub directory `root/windows/` to `root/windows/ct.php`

File structure of site is like

```
root/windows/ct.php
```

Redirect these type of url

```
http://www.site.com/windows/games/ or http://www.site.com/windows/games
http://www.site.com/windows/software/ or http://www.site.com/windows/software
```

To

```
http://www.site.com/windows/ct.php?ct=games
http://www.site.com/windows/ct.php?ct=software
```

I am trying like this but it redirects all url to sub directory `root/windows/ct.php`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/ /Site/windows/?ct=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/windows]*)/ /Site/windows/?ct=$1 [L] // this one shows internal server error
```

Complete .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^(error) - [L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/[^/]*/(.*\.html) /Site/error/400/ [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*\.html) /Site/software/?link=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/ /Site/windows/?ct=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/(.*?)\.xml$ rss/$1.php [L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 400 /Site/error/400/
```

I do not know well about .htaccess please see and suggest any possible way to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^windows/([^/]+)/?$ /windows/ct.php?ct=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

For your `localhost` use this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Site/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^windows/([^/]+)/?$ windows/ct.php?ct=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @TallboY Remove all your old .htaccess and use this one as is above

Comment: +1 this should work. @TallboY: tail your apache error log and see what is the error there.

Comment: @anubhava `[Wed Sep 04 18:58:03.913148 2013] [core:error] [pid 1748:tid 1548] [client 127.0.0.1:52441] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: @TallboY have you removed your old .htaccess and tried the above alone?

Comment: @Prix site structure is like `root/windows/ct.php`

Comment: where is your `.htaccess` inside the folder windows?

Comment: @TallboY then your folder structure is wrong otherwise it would work, how is your folder? `/home/youraccount/public_html/windows`?

Comment: @Prix yes exactly like that.

Comment: @TallboY then yes that should work, can you try from another browser just to make sure you're cache free.

Comment: @Prix but i am trying on local host so the structure is `wamp/www/Site/windows/`

Comment: @TallboY is the .htaccess on your localhost inside Site or www?

Comment: @Prix .htaccess path is `wamp/www/Site/.htaccess`

Comment: @TallboY now you can place your other rules on it ;) just wanted to make sure everything was good

Comment: @TallboY its good to use 302 instead of 301 when testing new rules to avoid caching the result until its working as you wanted it to. If the answer solves your issue kindly mark it :)

Comment: @TallboY it will only redirect non-existent files and folders, so if index.php exists there it will not redirect.

Comment: @Prix Hi can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227527/htaccess-pretty-url-lost-on-mobile-subdomain-redirect if you have time